# Email:MIME, sending in multipart with attachment?

Tags: perl, email, mime

This is driving me nuts. I must be missing something stupid. I have the following sub:

```
sub send_email {

    use MIME::Lite;
    use MIME::Base64;
    use Encode;

    my $to = 'support@foobar.co.uk'; #$rec{'Email'};

    my $from = $admin_email;
    my $subject = "webform $html_title";
    my $html = "some test <b>message</b> foo bar test";
    my $text = "some test message some plain version";

    # $html = decode( 'utf-8', $html );
    # $text = decode( 'utf-8', $text );

    my ($status,$attach,$newfile);

    use Email::MIME;
    use Email::Address::XS;
    use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
    use IO::All;
    use GT::MIMETypes;

# multipart message
    my @alternative_parts = (
        Email::MIME->create(
            body_str => $text,
            attributes => {
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                content_type => "text/plain",
                disposition  => "inline",
                charset      => "UTF-8",
            }
        ),
        Email::MIME->create(
            body_str => $html,
            attributes => {
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                charset  => "UTF-8",
                content_type => "text/html",
                disposition  => "inline",
            }
        )
    );

    my @attachment_parts;

    my $attach = "/path/to/file/tables.cgi";

    if ($attach) {

        my $filename = (reverse split /\//, $attach)[0]; # also change
+d in body => below
        my $content;

        my $mime = GT::MIMETypes::guess_type($filename);

        push @parts, Email::MIME->create(
            attributes => {
                filename     => $filename,
                content_type => $mime,
                encoding     => "base64",
                name         => $filename,
                attachment   => "attachment"
            },
            body => io( $attach )->binary->all,
        )
    }

    my $email = Email::MIME->create(
        header_str => [
            From => $from,
            To => [ $to ],
            Subject => $subject
        ],
        parts => \@parts,
        attributes => {
            encoding => 'base64',
            charset  => "UTF-8",
            content_type => "multipart/multipart",
            #disposition  => "inline",
        }
    );

    sendmail($email->as_string);

    print "EMAIL: " . $email->as_string. "\n\n"; # print for andy

}
```

What it needs to do is include both a plain text and HTML body of the email. Then, also attached is a file (a .cgi just for testing :)).

While the emails come through fine on Gmail - it buggers up on Outlook/Thunderbird. I have a feeling its the way I'm breaking up the "parts". From my understanding, you need a "main" body part, which can be split into a plain text and HTML version - and then the attachment as another part of the main "part". I'm not too sure how to achieve this though?

This is how the "debug_structure" comes out:

```
Structure: + multipart/multipart; boundary="15846317930.c94ff7.26547"
     + text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
     + text/html; charset="UTF-8"
     + text/plain; attachment="attachment"; name="tables.cgi"
```

**UPDATE:** As suggested, I'm now trying nested parts:

```
# multipart message
    my @message_parts = (
        Email::MIME->create(
            body_str => $text,
            attributes => {
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                content_type => "text/plain",
                disposition  => "inline",
                charset      => "UTF-8",
            }
        ),
        Email::MIME->create(
            body_str => $html,
            attributes => {
                encoding => 'quoted-printable',
                charset  => "UTF-8",
                content_type => "text/html",
                disposition  => "inline",
            }
        )
    );


    my @all_parts;
    push @all_parts, Email::MIME->create(
        parts => [\@message_parts], # add all the message parts into here...
        attributes => {
            content_type => "multipart/alternative"
        }
    );


    my $attach = "/home/user/web/public_html/cgi-bin/admin/tables.cgi";

    if ($attach) {

        my $filename = (reverse split /\//, $attach)[0]; # also changed in body => below

        # better to use GT::MIMETypes if you have it with Fileman (pretty sure you do?)
        my $mime = GT::MIMETypes::guess_type($filename);

        push @all_parts, Email::MIME->create(
            attributes => {
                filename     => $filename,
                content_type => $mime,
                encoding     => "base64",
                name         => $filename
            },
            body => io( $attach )->binary->all,
        )
    }


    my $email = Email::MIME->create(
        header_str => [
            From => $from,
            To => [ $to ],
            Subject => $subject
        ],
        parts => [\@all_parts],
        attributes => {
            encoding => 'base64',
            content_type => "multipart/mixed"
        }
    );

    print qq|Structure: | . $email->debug_structure. "\n\n";
```

But I get an error:

> Can't call method "as_string" on unblessed reference at
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Email/MIME.pm line 771.

Line 771 is in `parts_set` in Email::MIME - so I must be doing something wrong setting?

**UPDATE 2:** Thanks Steffen for your help! So this is the final working code, with the correct structure:

```
use Email::MIME;
use Email::Address::XS;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use IO::All;
use GT::MIMETypes;

my $to = 'support@foo.co.uk'; #$rec{'Email'};

my $from = $admin_email;
my $subject = "some title";
my $html = "some test <b>message</b> foo bar test";
my $text = "some test message some plain version";
$html = decode( 'utf-8', $html );
$text = decode( 'utf-8', $text );

# multipart message
my @message_parts = (
    Email::MIME->create(
        body_str => $text,
        attributes => {
            encoding => 'quoted-printable',
            content_type => "text/plain",
            disposition  => "inline",
            charset      => "UTF-8",
        }
    ),
    Email::MIME->create(
        body_str => $html,
        attributes => {
            encoding => 'quoted-printable',
            charset  => "UTF-8",
            content_type => "text/html",
            disposition  => "inline",
        }
    )
);


my @all_parts;
push @all_parts, Email::MIME->create(
    parts => \@message_parts, # add all the message parts into here...
    attributes => {
        content_type => "multipart/alternative"
    }
);


my $attach = "/home/user/web/foo.co.uk/public_html/cgi-bin/admin/tables.cgi";

if ($attach) {

    my $filename = (reverse split /\//, $attach)[0]; # also changed in body => below

    # better to use GT::MIMETypes if you have it with Fileman (pretty sure you do?)
    my $mime = "plain/text";  # hard coded in this example, but you want to set the correct type for the attachment type

    push @all_parts, Email::MIME->create(
        attributes => {
            filename     => $filename,
            content_type => $mime,
            encoding     => "base64",
            name         => $filename
        },
        body => io( $attach )->binary->all,
    )
}


my $email = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
        From => $from,
        To => [ $to ],
        Subject => $subject
    ],
    parts => \@all_parts,
    attributes => {
        encoding => 'base64',
        content_type => "multipart/mixed"
    }
);

print qq|Structure: | . $email->debug_structure. "\n\n";

sendmail($email->as_string);
```

The structure now comes out correctly as:

```
Structure: + multipart/mixed; boundary="15846944601.d6aF.12245"
     + multipart/alternative; boundary="15846944600.d79D2A2.12245"
          + text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
          + text/html; charset="UTF-8"
     + text/plain; name="tables.cgi"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `multipart/multipart` which you use. Your mail should have the following structure instead:

```
 multipart/mixed
 |- multipart/alternative   << mail client will choose which of the parts to display
 |  | text/plain            << the mail as plain text
 |  | text/html             << the mail as HTML
 |- text/plain              << the attachment
```

As for the attachment it might be useful to choose a `content-type` which better matches the attachment type. If the attachment is actually plain text then `text/plain` might be fine but if it is an image, office document, archive ... different `content-type` should be used.

Apart from that neither `encoding` nor `charset` nor `disposition` make any sense in a multipart definition. These are only relevant for final parts (`text/plain` etc), not for container parts (`multipart/whatever`)

```
    attributes => {
        encoding => 'base64',
        charset  => "UTF-8",
        content_type => "multipart/multipart",
        #disposition  => "inline",
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - not sure how multipart/multipart got in there :) Must have been staring at the code too long! I'm still trying to figure out how I get the required structure with `Email::MIME`. It lets you pass in `parts => [\@array_of_parts]`, but I don't see how you do sub-parts (i.e the text/html versions). I'll keep playing

Comment: @AndrewNewby: You currently already use `Email::MIME->create` to create single parts and also to create multiparts based on these parts. This can also be done nested, i.e. a multipart part inside a new multipart.

Comment: aaah right - I didn't realise I could use the "parts" bit in there as well. I'll give it a play :)

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I've included an updated example above. Basically, creating the plain text / html version in `@message_parts`, and then adding that into a new `@all_parts`, which I then also add the attachment to further down. It gives a fatal error though. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndrewNewby: it should not be `parts => [\@message_parts],` but `parts => \@message_parts,`, i.e. just an array reference and not an array with an array reference inside.

Comment: ahhhh man - I can't believe it was that stupid! Interestingly, the docs have ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME)  `Email::MIME->create( parts => [ @parts ] )` - that must have been where I got the [] bit from - duh!  It now exports perfectly - thank you so much :)